# Alienware 17 fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.2 can't connect wired or wirelessly

Tags: 14.04, alienware

### Problem

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 on my Alienware 17 laptop, and haven't been able to connect
to the internet through wifi or wired connection.

### Hardware

- Ethernet Controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
- Network Controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 003e (rev 20)

I also tried checking available drivers to install and didn't find any.

This is my result after running the command `lspci -n | egrep '0200|0280' | awk '{print$3}'`

```
1969:e091

168c:003e
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working: no network interface](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661424/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-not-working-no-network-interface)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I might share the same system with you. Is it Alienware 17 R2 2015? I tried to install ubuntu on my M.2 SSD with efi enabled, the installation process is successful but it won't boot. When booting it always fall back to initramfs/busybox command.

By the way, your wired and wireless card is from Qualcomm. Is it the killer 1525? This link below might be interesting with you. that is the driver for it.

https://github.com/sumdog/ath10k-firmware